# Which exchanges are currently the best and easiest to list ERC-20 tokens on?

Tags: tokens, exchanges

Which exchanges are currently the best and easiest to list ERC-20 tokens on?

Hello,

I am issuing ERC-20 tokens at the moment.

Which exchanges are the best and easiest to list tokens on at the moment? Preferably in just one or a few steps.

Vesa

Answer (score 1):

There are decentralized exchanges that do not require to "list" a token for users to be able to trade it.  One well known example is [EtherDelta](https://etherdelta.com/).  User may trade arbitrary token there just by entering its smart contract address.

Comment: That's true, I know about EtherDelta but I had forgotten about it. Also their UI is pretty hard to use, at least last time I tested it. Do you know any others?

Comment: Just checked ED, first time in a long time. I see they have a mobile interface now, that's better. I will try it out again some time. Still looking for a few more exchanges that accept new ERC-20 tokens as well.

Comment: ED is not the only decentralized exchange out there, but anyway, once you will distribute your tokens, token holders will start trading them on whatever decentralized exchanges they prefer.  You will not need to do anything about this, and basically you cannot do anything about this, unless your token smart contract supports address black list, and you will put some decentralized exchanges into it..